# Prove that A is denumerable iff A~B for every infinite B$\subseteq A$ and understanding

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let A be an infinite set.
Prove that A is denumerable iff A~B for every infinite B$\subseteq A$

**References**

**6.1** Definition By the set of the natural numbers we mean the intersection of all the successor sets. The set of the natural numbers is designated by the symbol ω; every element of ω is called a natural number.

**7.14** Theorem A is an infinite set if and only if A has a denumerable subset.

**Here are my thoughts on the matter** (rewrite from notes)

A being countably infinite an bijection  exists
h:B$\mapsto  \omega$

B$\subset $A is infinite.Thus there is an injection f:$\omega\mapsto $B

We ahave the canonical injection:i :B$\mapsto $A:
b$\mapsto $b:

Thus h$\circ i \circ $f $:B\mapsto \omega$ is injective.
Thus B is equipotent it’s subset and B is infinite.

QED

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is countably infinite, there is a bijection $h:A\to\omega$. Let $B$ be an infinite subset of $A$; then there is an injection $f:\omega\to B$, and of course we have the canonical injection $\iota:B\to A:b\mapsto b$, so $h\circ\iota:B\to\omega$ is an injection. Thus, $|B|=|\omega|$ by the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem. (Note that the composition $h\circ\iota\circ f$ is injective but not in general bijective.)

Now suppose that $|A|=|B|$ for each infinite $B\subseteq A$. $A$ is infinite, so there is an injection $f:\omega\to A$. Let $B=f[\omega]$; clearly $B$ is an infinite subset of $A$, so $|A|=|B|=|\omega|$, and $A$ is therefore countably infinite.

Comment: @Eudoxus: I don’t understand your reasoning for the converse; for starters, you seem to be assuming that $\omega\subseteq A$ when you write $g(m)=f(2m)$. Even if you really meant that $g\big(f(m)\big)=f(2m)$, I don’t see how $g$ helps you to show that $A$ is countably infinite. \\ If you don’t yet have the C-S-B theorem, is proving that there’s a bijection between $A$ and $B$ the only way that you have to show that $|A|=|B|$?

Comment: I can’t use Cantor Bernstein theorem. I got this idea from one of Charles Pinter’s theorem @BrianMScott So I guess g is wrong? I was wondering how to get B~$\omega$ When I get buggered,I need to know why and how to proceed. Thanx

Comment: I thought I had to show a subset by showing a bjiective function

Comment: @Eudoxus: Have you already proved that every infinite subset of $\omega$ is countably infinite?

Comment: It is a given in the text. I have given theorems on equipotence (1)A  $\leqslant$ B iff A is in one-to-one correspondence with a subset of B. S-B is introduced in the chapter on cardinals

Comment: @Eudoxus: It shouldn’t be a given: it actually does require proof. But if you do have that, you can simply note that $h\circ\iota$ is a bijection between $B$ and a subset of $\omega$, so $B$ is equipotent with that subset. And $B$ is infinite, so that subset is infinite and is therefore countably infinite.

Comment: Thanks. I could just reprove it